# How to downgrade .netcore sdk from 2.1.504 to 2.1.4 as server can only host upto sdk 2.1.4

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.1

My web application developed with vs on .netcore sdk 2.1.504 cannot be run on my server as it allows hosting only upto sdk 2.1.4. So is it possible to downgrade to 2.1.4 so as to host it on the server without having to build a new project?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but there was no global.json file. only appsettings.json, program.cs and startup.cs. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Define the specific version you want in [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) file:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.1.4"
  }
}
```

> .NET Core SDK looks for a global.json file in the current working directory (which isn't necessarily the same as the project directory) or one of its parent directories.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but there was no global.json file. only appsettings.json, program.cs and startup.cs. What can I do?

Comment: @Hnamte Answer edited. Read the link in the answer to more details. But I'm not sure that it will solve your problem, because I'm not sure your problem is really what you described. It sounded strange to me.